# How to syntactically call a method that takes a block in another method?

Tags: ruby, methods, block, yield

So I'm new to Ruby and I'm looking to make my code a little neater and cleaner looking. Basically I have a these methods in a class. I made a reverse polish notation calculator. Now I know in theory "don't repeat yourself" but as you can see in the `plus` `minus` `divide` and `times` methods I do. Basically the only thing that changes is a the +, -, /, *. I'm wondering what is the best way to go about fixing that? To start, here's the code. Some of my thoughts are below.

```
class RPNCalculator

def initialize
    @calculator =  [ ] 
end

def push(num)
    @calculator << num
end

def plus
    value = @calculator[-2].to_f + @calculator[-1]
    @calculator.delete_at(-2)
    @calculator.delete_at(-1)
    @calculator << value
end

def minus
    value = @calculator[-2].to_f - @calculator[-1]
    @calculator.delete_at(-2)
    @calculator.delete_at(-1)
    @calculator << value
end

def divide
    value = @calculator[-2].to_f / @calculator[-1]
    @calculator.delete_at(-2)
    @calculator.delete_at(-1)
    @calculator << value
end

 def times
    value = @calculator[-2].to_f * @calculator[-1]
    @calculator.delete_at(-2)
    @calculator.delete_at(-1)
    @calculator << value
end
```

Basically, I'm thinking to make another method `end_calc()` which takes a block(?). I'm wondering what that would look like. For example this is what I was thinking about.

```
def end_calc(&block)
value = @calculator[-2].to_f &block @calculator[-1]
    @calculator.delete_at(-2)
    @calculator.delete_at(-1)
    @calculator << value
end

def plus
  end_calc(+)
end
```

Basically in the methods `plus` `minus` etc, I just call end_calc plus the necessary `+` `-` `/` `*` sign. How can I write it syntactically so that the `+` method is inserted into `end_calc`? Or what should I go about studying in order to understand how to do that? Is there another what to do it that may be more effective that I do not know about yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
class RPNCalculator
  def initialize
    @calculator = []
  end

  def push(num)
    @calculator << num
  end

  def plus
    do_operation(:+)
  end

  def minus
    do_operation(:-)
  end

  def divide
    do_operation(:/)
  end

  def times
    do_operation(:*)
  end

  private

  def do_operation(operation)
    operand_2, operand_1 = @calculator.pop, @calculator.pop
    value = operand_1.to_f.send(operation, operand_2)
    @calculator << value
  end
end
```

Also, I think you should rename `times` to `multiply`, because method `times` is often used to repeat block of code several times and it may cause misunderstanding.

Comment: I used some Ruby magic here, can explain it if it isn't clear enough.

Comment: `operand_1, operand_2 = @calculator.pop(2)` :)

Comment: @cremno nice addition)